# FQL Filter user Table By name

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

It says in the [FQL user Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) that there are 4 indexable fields (marked with *):

- name
- third_party_id
- uid
- username

But when I perform a [query like this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20name%0AFROM%20user%20%0AWHERE%20name%20%3D%20%22Mark%20Zuckerberg%22):

```
SELECT uid
FROM user 
WHERE name = "Mark Zuckerberg"
```

I get an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain 
                an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the 
                tables linked from 
                http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? Is this a bug? How can I filter an FQL query on the user table by name?

Comment: This a bug filed here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331209630309433   You may want to add yourself and your app-id to this bug.  Then, you'll be subscribed to it.

Answer (score 3):

Awaiting response from FB on this bug, but meanwhile there is a workaround.

The indexable column name works in the profile table and can return its id field, which corresponds to the uid column in the user table, e.g.

```
SELECT first_name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT id FROM profile WHERE name="Mark Zuckerberg")
```

Comment: Two odd things here

        (1) the indexable property "name" is broken in one table yet working in another
        (2) two columns in different tables representing the same entity have different names.  That's just wrong.